How stop a process that is running in the background without closing the terminal?
So I ran the code sudo ./vhusbdarm64 &
But when I try to find the PID using ps aux | grep rot, I only get the following:
pi          2448  0.0  0.0   3968  1536 pts/0    S+   11:45   0:00 grep --color=                                                                                                             auto rot

How can I stop the process without closing the terminal?

Your command is vhusbdarm64, you're grepping for rot. What's the connection?

The easiest way to find your process is to use the jobs command which will list processes started in the current shell.   If the job is listed there, you can use the fg command (possibly with % and the job number) to bring it to the foreground.  Then you can interrupt it with ctrlc
If the process orphaned itself, there may not be a job left for this to work.
The next easiest way to find the job is with the ps t command which will list all processes on the current terminal.   Then you can use sudo kill with the job's pid listed by ps.
If the process disassociated itself from the terminal, this might not work either.  Rather than search for the job with the (presumably typoed) username, you should search by the command you typed, for example ps aux | grep vhusbdarm64
If even that doesn't show anything, maybe it already exited and is no longer running.
Note that if the process disassociated itself from the terminal, then there is a chance that closing the terminal as you originally suggested might not actually kill it!
As a final note, it was recommended you use kill -9.  I strongly discourage this as it does not give the targeted process any chance to clean up.  Usually kill with no specified signal is enough.  If it doesn't exit after a few seconds, only then would I use -9.

Your answer was well-explained and got the job done. Thanks!
